# Convert datetime in UTC format to GMT+7 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, utc, gmt

I have a datetime column in MySQL table in `Y-m-d H:i:s` UTC format:

```
SELECT `transaction_time` FROM `transaction` LIMIT 1;
//2018-10-12 09:36:12
```

the above wil show my database record which i alreade save in UTC format, how can i show it in GMT+7 format ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CONVERT_TZ() method.

```
Select CONVERT_TZ(`transaction_time`,'+00:00','+07:00') from `transaction` LIMIT 1;
```

[Refer to this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT_TZ()` function:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(transaction_time, '+00:00', '+07:00') FROM transaction LIMIT 1;
```

You can read more about `CONVERT_TZ()` function [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).